# UITextView Scrolling Indicator issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

My `UITextView` becomes scrollable at a certain number of lines. When I scroll up a paragraph of text, the scrolling indicator is not scrolling to the top of the `UITextView` but to the top of text container. Any suggestions?

Here's my `UITextView` code:

```
lazy var chatTextField: UITextView = {

    let chatText = UITextView()
    chatText.scrollIndicatorInsets.top = 0

    chatText.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-40, 0, 0, 0)
    chatText.delegate = self
    chatText.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    chatText.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 16)
    chatText.textColor = UIColor(r: 120, g: 128, b: 125)
    chatText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return chatText
}()
```

Take note of the scrolling indicator; it should be pushing the top part.

[image]

Comment: That's because this is actual height of your text view. You text above it because mask to bound is not active. Try checking this by setting background colour of your text view.

Comment: Yes, I tested by using blue awhile ago and clearly saw the problem there. However, when I make chatTextField.layer.maskToBounds = true, the result is the same.

Comment: Yeah that is right..   You extend your textView with message input view. that will resolve the issue.

Comment: unfortunately, that didn't work. I feel like there must be tricks to accomplish this. I tried `chatTextField.textViewInput.layer.maskToBounds = true` ..

Comment: There's no trick just do expanding right.. You can take a reference from here: https://github.com/rptwsthi/DevelopmentSupportWorkspace/tree/master/RptTextView I have created a expandable textview that accomplish all this.

Answer (score 0):

I use a collectionView and these lines of code work for me. Try:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {self.collectionView!.reloadData()
                    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: self.messages.count-1, inSection: 0)
                        self.collectionView?.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: true)
                    })
```